# In SQL Server, how do I set a cell to reference all values not in the other cells of that column (an Other category)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, if this column has values A, B, C, D, Others and is linked to another table's column that includes all alphabet values, and I'm trying to tie "Others" to all rows in the second table that do not include "A, B, C, or D" for that Column.

Comment: Sample data and a desired result would be very helpful.

Comment: Your question reads (to me) as if you were looking for [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/381c07/1). Please clarify. Feel free to update the fiddle.

Comment: If you are still looking for an answer to this question, please, provide more input.